# Using TPL Tasks with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library

I was hoping to use the System.Threading.Task library for my asynchronous web requests in my WP7 project. However, in WP7 (I believe) you have to use the HttpWebRequest class for http requests (something my app does a lot of). The HttpWebRequest class only has a BeginGetResponse method that forces you to use the old asynchronous programming model by requiring you to pass in a callback parameter.

Is there any way to enter modernity using WP7, or am I stuck with HttpWebRequests and callbacks?

UPDATE
Jon gave me some good direction on finding the right method to convert APM code to TPL using Task.Factory.FromAsync, but I am really struggling on using Task.Factory.FromAsync. The first parameter is an IAsyncResult, which I assume would be your BeginGetResponse or BeginGetRequest method. But the second parameter, which the documentation I've read typically suggests should be your end method, is a Func. The EndGetRequest and EndGetResponse methods for HttpWebRequest return a Stream ... and at that point, I'm lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can use [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321335.aspx) to build a `Task<T>` from a begin/end-method pair.

I don't know whether that's supported by the WP7 version of TPL, but it's where I'd start.

See also: ["TPL and Traditional .NET Framework Asynchronous Programming"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jon - I'll check it out!

Comment: Jon, do you know of any code samples that specifically create a Task<T> using HttpWebRequest HttpWebResponse? I have been struggling through that documentation, but I can't understand how to properly use the FromAsync overloads with the Begin and End methods for HttpWebResponse.

Comment: For example, it's easy to pass an IAsyncResult into FromAsync's first parameter (that's the Begin method). But in all overloads, the second parameter is of type Func<IAsyncResult,HttpWebRequest>. The End methods for HttpWebRequest/Response (which is what the documentation uses - the End method) return a Stream object. I'm struggling with how to properly cast or handle that - perhaps I need to add a type parameter to the FromAsync method - FromAsyn<T> - but nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: `Task.Factory.FromAsync((cb, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(cb, o), res => ((HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(res), req)`

Comment: Thanks Cory, that looks good (no errors) - but can you give a small explanation of what it's doing?? :) Too many lambdas still make me dizzy.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz: Basically it's telling the TPL, "Call this (first) delegate to start getting the response, and this (second) delegate to finish getting the response when the IAsyncResult completes."

Comment: Thanks! So -- how does one get those results? If it's not a Task<HttpWebRequest>, the task instance doesn't have a .result property ... my end goal here is to get the results from the response and bind them to a UI listbox.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz: it will be a `Task<WebResponse>`, because that's what `EndGetResponse` gives. If you're using C# 5, you can just use `var response = await task;`

Comment: Thanks Jon! It's awesome to see all the red squigglies go away :). I am struggling to get a value in result, but I think I've exhausted this thread. I've posted my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651255/taskwebresponse-result-is-always-null