# Task<WebResponse>.Result is always null

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm working on some code to do an HttpRequest via Task.Factory.FromAsync (in a WP7 app).

The task's Result property is always null, but I know the request itself is correct, because if I paste it into my browser or Fiddler, it works. This is my code:

```
        string _url = string.Format("http://requestapi.net/{0}/{1}/{2}", 
            "objects","partitionKey","pkey1");
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        Task<WebResponse> task1 = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
            (callback, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(callback, o)
            , result => ((HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result)
            , request);

        task1.Start();
        WebResponse webResponse = task1.Result;
        string responseString;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse)
        {
            using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

UPDATE: on WP7, the TPL is only available via Nuget. I downloaded it here: 
http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks

UPDATE: 
This works. Mike was right - the task just wasn't finished executing. I'm not sure why task1.Result didn't wait automatically (it's supposed to implicitly call task1.wait()), but this is the working code. Please let me know if you see other problems with this! This code starts where the task1.Start() used to be - which is now removed.

```
            //task1.Start();
            string responseString;
            task1.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
            {

                WebResponse webResponse = task1.Result;

                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse)
                {
                    using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `await`?

Comment: My understanding is that task1.Result makes an implicit call to .Wait ... but I'll try your suggestion. I'm not familiar with the difference between Wait and Await :)

Comment: `await` is a compiler construct, it doesn't block the thread but it re-factors all your code to move everything after the `await` into another callback function.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Start` on a `Task` unless you created it via it's constructor (you're not here, you're using `FromAsync`).

Comment: @MikeChristensen He may be having issues by blocking the thread when he shouldn't, but that wouldn't cause the result to be null.  It would either result in freezing the app for the duration if it's a UI app, or possibly deadlocking the code if he's `Wait`ing on callbacks that need that context.

Comment: @Servy - I kinda think `FromAsync()` is starting the task, the thread is not blocked, `.Start()` is a no-op because the task is already started, and then he immediately checks `.Result` which is null because he isn't `await`ing the results of the task which hasn't finished yet.

Comment: @MikeChristensen As per the msdn docs for `Start`, it will throw an exception if you try to start an already started task.  `FromAsync` will indeed start the task before returning it.  `.Result` will internally call `Wait` if the task has not finished.  You don't need to `await` the task, and it's not at all clear that doing so would even be appropriate in this context; I'm thinking that it would *not* be.

Comment: @Servy - Ah, good point.  I'm not super familiar with the Silverlight framework on WP7, but from what I've seen it doesn't let you do anything synchronously or block anything ever.  So I'm thinking it might be implemented in a different way.

Comment: I'm not sure whose theory this supports, but if I take the task.Start() out of my code, it seems to completely exit on the line task1.Result; If I put a breakpoint on the next line (string responsestring;), it never gets hit.

Comment: It supports my theory that Windows Phone programming is weird..

Comment: When I break on task1.Result, the value in the locals window for task1 = Id = 0, Status = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation, Result = ""

Comment: Did you try making it: `WebResponse response = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(...);`

Comment: I'm not sure I have access to await. The compiler says "The name 'await' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: AAAhhhhhhh ... I used ContinueWith and placed my logic there, and it seems to be running gloriously. I'll update the post. Mike, you put the idea in my head that the task simply wasn't done (I had assumed I was just using FromAsync wrong). Do you want to write an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: You can't call Start on that task: "Start may not be called on a task with null action.". So the code shown is not the code that you executed.

Comment: Good info - but I did call start on it, and it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: And .Result *does* block. Maybe a WP discrepancy?! Eerie. I just reproduced it on the PC which behaves just as I say.

Comment: It's a different library, I think, as I noted in my post. I had to add it to my project via Nuget, with the -pre attribute in there, so I assume there are a few differences. Fortunately, nothing that kept me from getting this working now :)

Comment: @usr - Yea, in Silverlight basically nothing can block..  Since it was originally written for web browsers, they were afraid of people writing crappy code that hosed the whole web page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically creating a task, but not waiting for it to complete before checking the result.  From the comments, it seems the WP7 runtime and framework work a bit differently from the full CLR, which would block when you tried to get the result.  The Silverlight runtime is very anti-blocking-things.

You'll want to use the `await` keyword (which is available on newer runtimes or using the [Async Targeting Pack](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack) if you have VS2012) or the `ContinueWith` method to start your task asynchronously.